# VirtualEnv ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, mysql-python

I am receiving the error: `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb` whenever I try to run my local dev server and it is driving me crazy. I have tried everything I could find online:

1. `brew install mysql`
2. `pip install mysqldb`
3. `pip install mysql`
4. `pip install mysql-python`
5. `pip install MySQL-python`
6. `easy_install mysql-python`
7. `easy_install MySQL-python`
8. `pip install mysqlclient`

I am running out of options and can't figure out why I continue to receive this error. I am attempting to run my local dev server from using Google App Engine on a macOS Sierra system and I am using python version 2.7. I am also running: `source env/bin/activate` at the directory my project files are and am installing all dependencies there as well. My path looks like this:

`/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

Does anyone have further ideas I can attempt to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should use PyMySQL.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in the virtual env (`source venv/bin/activate`), just run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

You don't have to import anything in your py files.

The first one is just in case, but the other two work perfectly by themselves.

If you don't run `libmysqlclient-dev`, you won't be able to run any other mysql installation command while in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the wrong python being pointed to in my virtualenv. It comes preinstalled with its own default python version and so, I created a new virtualenv and used the `-p` to set the python path to my own local python path.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, with virtualenv, I just did

> pip install mysqlclient

and like magic everything is ok